# How to handle stream in the background?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm requesting a server and server responses a `Stream`. The first element in the stream is the data updates the UI but other `Stream` events needs to be in the background. I have to return `stream.first` back in order to update the state.

```dart
Future<AccountResponse> cEAccount(Account request) async {
  final stream = client.cEAccount(request).asBroadcastStream();
  final firstRes = await stream.first;

  watchBlockchainResponse(stream);

  return firstRes;
}
```

```dart
Future watchBlockchainResponse(Stream stream) async {
  await for (final res in stream) {
    ...
}
```

`watchBlockchainResponse` shows an overlay using [`overlay_support`](https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_support/install). This code is working fine. Is this a good practice? If not, how should I handle this?

Comment: can't you just use stream.listen?

Comment: definitely forgot that exists. Seems like it could get the job done. TY!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```dart
stream.listen((res) {

});
```